# Why did upgrading WAMPServer's PHP from 7.3.12 to 7.4.0 cause Argon2i error?

Tags: php, wamp, php-7.4, libsodium

When I upgraded my WAMPServer's PHP from 7.3.12 to 7.4.0, my site now says:

> This is not implemented, as it is not possible to implement Argon2i with acceptable performance in pure-PHP

I've been searching but can't find why the upgrade would break my site in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/331992 , which is about Magento, which is unrelated to anything I'm using, but it hints that I'm missing the Sodium PHP extension.

Enabling "sodium" in WAMP's extensions fixed it for me:

[image]